# How to draw the route between my current location and destination?

Tags: java, android

Right now, all this code shows is two markers, one at current location and the other at the destination specified. I need the route between them.i have posted the code of my MapsActivity below. I know we have to use JSON and polyline to get the job done but dontknow where and how to use them.

```
MapsActivity.java
package gcmojo.com.location;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
  GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
  LocationListener {
    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;


    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    double currentLatitude;
    double currentLongitude;
    EditText loc;
    String loca;
    String country;
    TextView myAddress;
        /*text view for mentioning the destination*/





    @
    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

      mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();

      mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        .setInterval(10 * 1000) // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
        .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
    }

    @
    Override
    protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      setUpMapIfNeeded();
      mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @
    Override
    protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      super.onPause();
      if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
      }
    }
    //method for current location
    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
      Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

      double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
      double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

      LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);


      // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title(coun));
      MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latLng)
        .title(getCompleteAddressString(currentLatitude, currentLongitude));
      mMap.addMarker(options);
      float zoomLevel = (float) 15.0;
      mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoomLevel));
    }


    //method for placing marker at destination via destination address
    public void onClick(View view) {
      loc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
      loca = loc.getText().toString();
      List < android.location.Address > addressList = null;
      if (loca != null || loca.equals("")) {

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
          addressList = gc.getFromLocationName(loca, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        android.location.Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());




        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ll).title("YO"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll));


      }


    }





    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
      if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
          .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {

          setUpMap();
        }
      }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
      mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
      if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
      }
      if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
      }
      mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }



    @
    Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");
      if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
      }
      if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
      }
      Location location =    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
      if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
      } else {
        handleNewLocation(location);
      }

    }

    @
    Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
    }

    @
    Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

      if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
          // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
          connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
      }
    }

    @
    Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    private String getCompleteAddressString(double latitude, double longitude) {
      String strAdd = "";
      Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
      try {
        List < android.location.Address > addresses = geocoder
          .getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (addresses != null) {
          android.location.Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
          StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

          for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
            strReturnedAddress
              .append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(
                "\n");
          }
          strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
        }
        /*  Log.w("My Current loction address", "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
            } else {
                Log.w("My Current loction address", "No Address returned!");
            } */
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Log.w("My Current loction address", "Canont get Address!");
      }
      return strAdd;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please explain the "various" things that you tried.

Comment: And describe the problem much more specifically than "nothing worked".

Comment: Plz check if the question is clear now, thx

Comment: If u cn uz rl wds tht wd b mch aprctd - y mk it hrdr 4 ur rdrs to ndrstd wht ur tkin abt?

Comment: I hope its all clear now

Answer (score 0):

include this in your app build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...

    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'

}
```

This library has the class PolyUtil. I don't know which Direction JSON parser you are using but I am pretty sure it will have a function that will return you the encoded polyline String. And then use the encoded string like below

```
public void drawPolyline (){
    String polylinePoints = YourParser.getPolylinePoints();
    List<LatLng> pointsList = PolyUtil.decode(points);
    mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().width(30).color(android.R.color.black).addAll(pointsList));

}
```